# How to use ASP.NET MVC 4 with preinstalled JQuery UI library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

So having successfully used JQuery Mobile with my mobile application I was looking to use JQuery UI with my web application. My web application is an ASP.NET MVC 4 project created in Visual Studio 2012.

However, I realised that when I created the MVC 4 project, it actually already includes JQuery UI - it's just not being used currently.

I noticed that the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC website doesn't make any mention to the preinstalled JQuery and JQuery UI libraries in any of its tutorials or code samples, which I find odd. I also noticed that none of my MVC 4 books gave any reference to the preinstalled JQuery libraries.

So my question is, I have JQuery UI preinstalled, how do I start making use of the files? I mean I guess I'll reference them from my Views, but which files do I reference?

Is there any existing documentation that would help me make the most of the preinstalled JQuery libraries?

Comment: I believe the default master page already comes with links to the jqueryUI js/css files. Documentation for jquery? Um, have you tried jquery.com?

Comment: You are free to use any version of jquery with mvc. Just reference jquery script from within your view or shared layout view.

Comment: @BradM, I'm well aware of the documentation available on jquery.com, my question was really to see if there are any documentation on how to make the best of Query within the context of an MVC4 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MVC4 everything should be preset for you in `BundleConfig.cs`  (App_Start folder)
Just include the bundles that you want to use.
usually for Javascript you only need `jquery-ui-{version}.js` file, and the rest is css styling that you want to apply.

*Note: make sure that you're using the latest jquery UI. if it is not the latest, I suggest to update your Jquery UI directly through package manager.*